# Writing a Bash script without the shebang line

Tags: bash

I wrote a bash script under CentOS and it was executed well. On another computer it was wrong. I forgot the shebang at the beginning, but why was it good on my computer?
I assume it's a very beginner question, but I gave it a try. Thanks.

Updated:
Another question popped up. What's the difference between executing with **./filename.sh** and **sh filename.sh**?

Comment: Did you run it with `sh script.sh`? In this case you won't need a shebang because the shell will already know which executable to run it with.

Comment: I used scriptname.sh <parameters> to run it and it went well. Why?

Comment: did you make it executable on the other system? try running it as `./scriptname.sh` instead of `scriptname.sh`

Comment: You mean you ran it with `./scriptname.sh <params>`? Or you put it somewhere in the $PATH?

Comment: I did not put it in the $PATH

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script execution with and without shebang in Linux and BSD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268437/bash-script-execution-with-and-without-shebang-in-linux-and-bsd)

Comment: *"On another computer it was wrong."*  I presume that means the computer reached out and slapped you in the face when you ran the script.  If not, please tell us what happened when you tried to run the script (exact error message if any, etc.)

Comment: It says _"Command not found"_. I assume it is what you all said, without shebang, I need to use sh.

Comment: I think the accepted answer already answers you updated question.

Comment: So ./ will execute it with the previous running shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not having a shebang in the beginning of your script will get it executed in whatever shell is currently running when the script was invoked. If you know for sure that the script will be launched from bash, and not from any other shell (ksh, csh, etc.), there is no need for a shebang, because the same interpreter will be launched.

Comment: also, I believe some systems use aliasing so calling `sh` may actually run a different shell

Comment: This is not always true. I've seen shells that start `/bin/sh` rather than themselves as default.

Comment: `bash` is actually the only shell that starts itself. All other shells use `sh`, including `zsh`, `ksh`, `dash`, plus any tool using the `exec*p` family of functions.

Comment: @thatotherguy, eh? the `exec*` functions typically just fail, rather than using `/bin/sh`, in the absence of any shebang.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `exec*p` uses `sh`. Other non-`p` `exec*` functions will fail. It's documented [in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html).

Answer (score 4):

If `execve` fails for your script, which it will, `/bin/sh` will be used. On one system `/bin/sh` may be a POSIX `sh` and on another it may be an alias for `bash`; your script probably relies on `bash` features.

Comment: Some shells do this, but not all -- I've seen shells that use themselves rather than `/bin/sh` as default.